# Anyone know if this 'dapps resolver' site is safe to connect wallet to?

Tags: dapps

Does anyone know if this is a legit site or not?
https://prodigyf.my.canva.site/dappsresolver

I'm trying to send dogecoin from BNB network to doge network in metamask so I can buy Omnom. When I put the receiving doge network address in I get 'not eth network, set to lowercase'.

I asked in the discord support for Omnom and they said "Use the  Dappsconfig and select rectification, once you are done with the rectification process, open metamask, goto settings- Advance settings- clear activities nonce and data. You should have the issue resolved that way."

I'm just wary of connecting my wallet to a random site like this.
Thanks for your help.